# Google Webfonts on iPhone iOS 4

Tags: ios, font-face

I have been using Google Webfonts for a while now.  I know that it is supposed to be compatible with iOS4 and up on the iPhone, iPod, etc.

I have recently looked at a couple of sites on my 2nd Gen iPod that runs version 4.2.1 (as far as I can upgrade it on a 2nd gen iPod) and the Google Webfonts are not working.  Now I KNOW that these worked before as I checked on my iPod before setting the sites live.  Other @font-face fonts that do not use Google Webfonts are working just fine on these sites.

I use the standard link tag as below:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

I have checked on a 4th Gen iPod and all fonts are showing fine so it must be down to the iOS version

Why has Google Webfonts suddenly stopped working on iOS 4?  How can I get it to work again.  Or failing that I need to be able to detect if the iOS is < iOS4 so that I can serve up a seperate CSS with the @font-face for truetype fonts rather than relying on Google Webfonts.

Comment: Can no one help me with this?  I am really confused as to why it would suddenly stop working in iOS 4

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm that my websites also stopped displaying webfonts from Google but still display webfonts from Myfonts.com, on my old iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1. Webfonts from Myfonts.com are stored on my server, along with HTML,CSS, JS, …, and Google webfonts are loaded dynamically from Google servers, as usual.
As a sidenote, Android 2.3-based phone still displays Google webfont correctly.

Comment: Ya I can confirm this as well. No solution though I suppose. :/